# Мой код не правильно находит дубликаты в списке

Tags: python

```
Coordinates_list = ["a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "a", "d"]
IDs_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Duplicates_ID = []
for n in range(len(Coordinates_list)):
  if Coordinates_list[n] in Coordinates_list[n-1]: Duplicates_ID.append(IDs_list[n])

print(Duplicates_ID)
```

Почему результат: [1, 3, 4]?
Хотя должен быть: [1, 3, 4, 5]

Код ниже вроде более логический правильный, результат [1, 3, 4, 5]:

```
Coordinates_list = ["a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "a", "d"]
IDs_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Duplicates_ID = list()
for i in range(len(Coordinates_list)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(Coordinates_list)):  
    if j < len(Coordinates_list) and Coordinates_list[i] == Coordinates_list[j]: Duplicates_ID.append(IDs_list[j])
    else: pass
Duplicates_ID = list(set(Duplicates_ID))
print(Duplicates_ID)
```

Comment: У вас очень странный и не очень питонический код. Объясните вкраце, что он делает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сравнивая с  `Coordinates_list[n-1]` ты сравниваешь с предыдущим элементом (кроме первого, который сравнивается с последним). Поэтому 5 не выводится - `a` не содержится в `c`.

*PS.  Слово "сравнивать" употреблено в переносном смысле, потому что `in` -никакое это не сравнение, но в данном случае сравнение.*

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с ответом [@Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1047155/217579), у вас не совсем верным подход к этому вопросу.
Нужно сравнивать не с предыдущи элементом, а с предыдущиМИ.

```
coordinates_list = ["a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "a", "d"]

duplicates_id = list()
for i, letter in enumerate(coordinates_list):
   if coordinates_list[i] in coordinates_list[:i]:
      duplicates_id.append(i)

print(duplicates_id)
```

Вывод: [1, 3, 4, 5]

**P.S.**
А если извратиться, то можно всё в одну строку 'пихнуть'

```
duplicates_id = [i for i, letter in enumerate(coordinates_list) if coordinates_list[i] in coordinates_list[:i]]
```

Comment: @NurJ, извини за очевидность, но скорее всего, потому что метод не верный и, если честно, не особо хочется разбираться почему. Думаю тебе лучше ещё раз хорошенько продумать  что делает каждая стока, точнее что выводит, тогда всё поймёшь или через обычные принты посмотри что да как

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

a = [1,2,3,2,1,5,6,5,5,5]
print [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1]
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835762/how-do-i-find-the-duplicates-in-a-list-and-create-another-list-with-them)